# High frequency clock from clocked RS latch

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop, latch, clock-speed

We were taught that this circuit is not of much use as when CLK=1, J=1 & K=1, Q toggles at a very high rate. So suppose I want to make a high-frequency clock, can I use this? 
Of course, the frequency itself can't be changed for given logic gates, but can I make a clock from this by giving high inputs at CLK,J and K? (I don't care about the exact frequency, it should just be like in MHz)

[image]

Comment: Possibly, but there are more reliable ways to make oscillators, why go for this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JK latch with both inputs tied high and clock high forms what’s called a *gated ring oscillator*. This is a legitimate circuit used on chips, forming the heart of circuits like phase lock loops and internal oscillators.

However, implementing these out of board level gates needs some further work to characterize and make stable. It is possible to create ring oscillators using a series of inverters fed back crosswise, and also inserting RC delays in those feedbacks. This is somewhat more controllable than just using a single JK latch.

More here: https://www.elprocus.com/ring-oscillator-working-and-its-applications/

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a JK or any other Flip-Flop unless you already have a clock.

Thus you can make a new clock signal with a lower frequency but not higher.
The nearest is a divide-by-two. Thus new_freq = old_freq/2.
With more FF's you can make a divide by 4,8,16 etc.

With some extra gates you can make a divide by 3, 5, 7.
You can not make a divide by a fraction unless you start using more special circuits like a PLL.

Answer (score 0):

A J-K or any D type flip-flop will not generate a clock of its own. Tying J and K together create a D type flip flop with the outputs fed back to input so it toggle on the rising edge of a clock pulse, just like the D type will do if /Q is tied back to the D input. You can chain them together with /Q output tied to the clock input of the next stage, which gives you a simple ripple counter.

You can use a CMOS 555 timer to get a basic clock pulse to experiment with.